# In $C_0$, the convergence $\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}\to f'(x)$ is uniform

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $C_0$ be the Banach space space of continuous real valued functions on the real line that vanish at infinity with the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.
>
> Let $f$ belong to $C_0$. Show that $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}(x)$ belongs to $C_0$ if and only if 
>   $
> \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t} 
> $
>   converges uniformly to $\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}(x)$ for $t\rightarrow 0$.

The challenging thing to proof here is $(\Rightarrow)$.

Remark: this is not an exercise I've been asked to do, just something I've stumbled upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the formula

$$\frac{f(x+t) - f(x)}{t}= \int_0^1 f'(x + a t)\, d a$$

It also works if $f$ takes values in a Banach space.

Comment: That great, let me use also that I now that in $C_0$, $f'(x-t)$ converges uniformly to $f'(x)$ for $t\rightarrow 0$, so take $\delta$ s.t. $\|f'(x+t)-f'(x)\|<\varepsilon$ for $|t|<\delta$ and then
$$
|\int_0^1 f'(x+at) da - f'(x)|< \int_0^1|f'(x+at) - f'(x)|da < \varepsilon \quad \forall x
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: since $\frac{d}{dt}f$ is $C_o$, given $\epsilon>0$, we can separate $\mathbb{R}$ into two parts, that is for $|x|>M$ ,$|\frac{d}{dt}f(x)|<\epsilon$, and $x\in[-M,M]$, $\frac{d}{dt}f(x)$ is uniformly continuous. Then use MVT for the quotient.
$$|\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t} -\frac{d}{dt}f(x)|=|\frac{d}{dt}f(\xi)-\frac{d}{dt}f(x)|$$

For $|x|>M$, $|\frac{d}{dt}f(\xi)-\frac{d}{dt}f(x)|\le|\frac{d}{dt}f(\xi)|+|\frac{d}{dt}f(x)|\le 2\epsilon $

For $|x|<M$, $|\frac{d}{dt}f(\xi)-\frac{d}{dt}f(x)|< 2\epsilon $ for small $t$ uniformly by uniformly continuous of $\frac{d}{dt}f(x)$ on $[-M,M]$.

You may need to take care of the range of $x$ and $x+t$, but the idea is similar, since you can assume $|t|<1$.